# When filtering a left join JavaRDD, Absent (or Present) cannot be cast to Optional exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am essentially trying to "subtract" using a left outer join instead.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> allCustomers = ... (customerID, 1)
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> excludedCustomers = ... (customerID, 1)

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Optional<Integer>>> joinedCustomers = allCustomers.leftOuterJoin(excludedCustomers)

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Tuple2<Integer, Optional<Integer>>> filteredCustomers = joinedCustomers.filter(t -> !t._2._2.isPresent())
```

But I get the errors

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.base.Present cannot be cast to com.google.common.base.Optional
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.base.Absent cannot be cast to com.google.common.base.Optional
```

I tried other workarounds, like mapping first and/or using .orNull, but I still get the same error.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Boolean> joinedCustomersBoolean = joinedCustomers.mapValues(t -> t._2.orNull() == null);
```

Last, but not least, setting `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst = true` does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you don't have different versions of guava library in your runtime classpath. Guava can come from: spark(prebundled), you code, hadoop classpath(if you use it/add it). In general you have two options: either downgrade your version to version that spark uses(this is simplest). Or you should prepare uber-jar & repackage your guava version into different package(see maven shade plugin). A bit hard to tell without additional information what is exact cause.